# Why is my Colorbox not working?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have used Colorbox several times in the past, however, for some reason, I cannot get it to work this time.

Below is my project page. My goal is when clicking on "Request Info", the form link populates within the pop-up Colorbox, but it doesn't.

Any help that you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

http://www.saintleo.edu/VirtualTour/video.html

Kind regards,

JK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 224 of "Generated Source Code" you have Jquery 1.7.1 included that override your jQuery 1.9.x from meta header. Make sure you use only on JQuery ...

Comment: Ahhhh!  Thanks so much for catching that!  Something so simple and now it's working!  Is it possible for me to use multiple colorboxes?  For example to attach one to the next image "Schedule a Visit" without causing problems?

Comment: yes you can use colorbox on multiple link see the example of colorbox, they are multiple only :).

Comment: Great!  Is it possible to make them different sizes?  For example, different widths?  If so, how?